# simple phone number regex not working

Tags: jquery, regex

My Data: **(222) 222-2222**

Why is this not passing?

```
checkRegexp(TelephoneNumber, /^(d{3}) d{3}-d{4}$/, "Please enter your 10 digit phone number.");


function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
              if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
                  o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                  updateTips(n);
                  return false;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(` and `)` are special characters in regular expressions meant to capture groups, you need to escape them. You also want to have `\d` for the digit characters. Without the `\` you are matching the letter `d`.

```
/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

When you have a problem with a regex, you can use a website like http://regex101.com/ that includes an explanation of your regular expression. You would have seen that the parentheses were not treated as literal characters.

For example, you original regex:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (d{3})
d{3} matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
Quantifier: Exactly 3 times
  matches the character   literally
d{3} matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
Quantifier: Exactly 3 times
- matches the character - literally
d{4} matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
Quantifier: Exactly 4 times
$ assert position at end of the string
```

You would have seen the problem easily.